# Ant build executes cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, ant

I created an ant build for my cordova project as following:

```
<project default="build">
    <target name="init-android">
        <exec executable="cordova">
            <arg value="platform"/>
            <arg value="add"/>
            <arg value="android"/>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="cordova">
            <arg value="build"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

But I got this error:

> C:\path_to_project\build.xml:3: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "cordova": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot
>   find the file specified
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Jav
>   a13CommandLauncher.java:41)

I can run cordova command with no problem from the command prompt, I have:

> JAVA_HOME = C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/ 
>   ANT_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2 
>   NODEJS_HOME = C:\Program Files\nodejs

and they are all in my path. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally when working with a Java application to launch programs in Windows, I often have to execute `cmd.exe` and pass it the full path to the program I actually want to run.  This allows system environment variables and such to be set up the way you expect.  Try this:

```
<project default="build">
    <target name="init-android">
        <exec executable="cmd.exe">
            <arg value="/C"/>
            <arg value="cordova"/>
            <arg value="platform"/>
            <arg value="add"/>
            <arg value="android"/>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="cmd.exe">
            <arg value="/C"/>
            <arg value="cordova"/>
            <arg value="build"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

If that still doesn't work, give the full path for cordova.  An environment variable should work if you have one defined.

Comment: Thank you. It works but then why my code doesn't work? There must be st wrong with my path?

Comment: I can no longer recall the root of the issue, but for some reason environment properties don't get passed transitively the way you would expect.  However, invoking `cmd.exe` causes all of the environment properties to be loaded and you're off to the races.

Comment: for cross platform compatibility with this - add the osfamily attribute <exec osfamily="windows" executable="cmd.exe">