# Do apache ant supports cordova to build native mobile apps?

Tags: cordova, jenkins, ant, ionic-framework

I need to package an app which is created with the support of ionic framework. Apache Cordova allows for building native mobile applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But i have used jenkins(CI tool) with ant, so how do integrate cordova with apache ant?

Helps Appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use the exec task in order to call cordova:

```
<exec executable="cordova" dir="...">
    <arg value="build"/>
    <arg value="android"/>
    <arg value="--release"/>
</exec>
```

The example above executes: cordova build android --release.

Further information in the ant manual: http://ant.apache.org/manual/ (go to: ant tasks / overview)

Cordova is not installed. refer the image.

Comment: where can i get the cordova package?

Comment: [cordova.apache.org/#getstarted](http://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted) or when the app uses ionic then you better follow their guide: [ionicframework.com/getting-started/](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). However, both use node.js and are installed using node.js. If you are completely new to this, maybe [taco.tools](http://taco.tools/) can help you with an easier setup. I havn't tested it...

Comment: After successful installation of node.js, tried to install cordova. while progress its wind up without any error. but cordova is not installed.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea, i'm using arch linux. maybe the following helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19160073/3204042

Comment: @ Falco Preiseni, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19160073/3204042 it helped me. But the same way how to do this in mac. Because "cmd.exe" could be used in windows.